# What is the character code for enter?

Tags: javascript, html, unicode

Consider this piece of code:
http://jsfiddle.net/YttKb/

I want my javascript to add a new line of text. I am using utf-8 coding. What character I need to insert to make a new line? Obviously `\n` doesn't create new line of text(creates only new line break). While `\n\n` creates a new line.

**EDIT:**

I have updated the fiddle. If you push enter manually at the end of the first line it does not create a new line as desired even though there is a line break(`\n`)

Comment: `\n` is a line break. Inserting one will create a new line.  If you insert `\n` twice, you’ll have to new lines. Since there’s nothing between the two line breaks, you’ll have created an empty line.

Comment: *"If you push enter manually at the end of the first line it does not create a new line as desired even though there is a line break(\n)"* Works for me. If I go to http://jsfiddle.net/YttKb/, put my cursor after the last "Hello World", and press enter, I go to the next line. If I press enter again, it moves down again, leaving a blank line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit platform-specific. It'll usually be `\n` or `\r\n`.

Of course, if you're talking about HTML, none of those will make a difference because in HTML (unless you're dealing with `pre` formatting, either the `pre` element or anything with the various `pre`-like values for `white-space` in their styles), whitespace is just a space. You'd need to use an element to break things up vertically (`<br>`, or something more appropriate to what you're doing).

Looking at your fiddle, you're dealing with HTML, so `\n`, `\r\n`, etc. are irrelevant. Here's an updated one doing this:

```
$("#test").append("<br>And hello from script");
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a3qN3/)

...but `<br>` is usually a last resort. There's usually something more semantically-appropriate you can do.

Comment: @Dharman: Is the output HTML (as in your fiddle), or was that a red herring?

Comment: The question helped me as it turns out `<br>`tag is added although the answer wasn't as I would expect(probably my fualt, should asked more clearly)

Comment: Whitespace is still there in html, it's just matter of css how it's displayed. Try `white-space: pre;` or the others.

Comment: @Esailija: Fair point, indeed.